# How to describe the dish is of little amount

Tags: word-choice, word-usage

Is there any fixed usage to describe that the food's amount is too little (far less than expectation).

For example, one scenario would be :

> That restaurant's food tastes good, but (food/dish's amount is too little)

Comment: The [**portions (1.2)**](https://www.lexico.com/definition/portion) are (very) small.

Comment: "... but you don't get much."

Comment: As per @WeatherVane, "The food is good, but the portions are too small."

Comment: I once saw, in a review: "portion size: we were lucky there was a KFC on the way home".

Comment: “It was good, what there was of it.”

Comment: Old UK joke - Waiter: How did you find your steak, sir? Diner: I just moved my peas and there it was!

Answer (score -1):

How about ". . the portions are disappointingly diminutive"

Comment: Since there are quite a number of ways to say this, including several that would be simpler, you might want to explain what you'd be trying to convey by choosing this particular expression.

Comment: Point taken. This might be appropriate if the speaker were pretentious.